# Send file to client without type it's name and file extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, filestream, file-transfer

I'm sending file over socket. Server to clients. Server read file and send. Client received file and write it and save it using file.write() But I have to type file name and file extension after/before it received. I don't want to type file name, extension. There is another way to receive file without do this. 
Here is my code:

```
# server send file to client.
Def send_file_to_client(conn):
           File = open("video.mp4", 'rb')
           Conn.send(File)
           print("file send.")

# client receive file from server.
Def recvfile():
         file = open("video.mp4", 'wb')
         while True:
                 r = soc.recv(4096)
                 if not r: break
                file.write(r)
        print("file download")
```

Comment: It is unclear for me what your problem is. You don't send a file but data (contents of the file). If you want to have these data associated with a file name you have to somehow provide it. If you trust the server to not only provide the content of the file but also the file name then let the server send the file name too over the socket and let the client read it and use it. If you don't trust the server you either provide the file name to your program or let your program create some unique file name itself.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich     Oh! I'm sending file data(contents of the file) not actually a file. So how to send/receive a file not contents of the file? Do you have any suggestions and examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without hard-coding the file name in the program, you can pass it through command line arguments while running the code.

Here is the link to GitHub where I implemented similar stuff:

[Reliable File Transfer over UDP](https://github.com/KiranMayeeMaddi/ReliableFileTransferOverUDP/tree/master/GoBackNARQ)

Hope this helps!

Comment: do you have any suggestions or examples. I need examples. A code of it. So I can understand  how to do that.

Comment: Tap on the link I posted. It will redirect to my github account. You can find the code in my repository. Check ReadMe file too, you will find instructions to pass arguments through command line.